# Get one textbox to fill two different tables

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have looked everywhere for this and I cant find anyone to do this. Should I Write a query for this instead? If not here is my code that works for the first table but not the second:

```
    DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
    DataRow row2 = ds2.Tables[0].NewRow();

        row[1] = DateText.Text;           //This adds all the datapoints to a Temperary table
        row[2] = IPNText.Text;
        row[3] = MoldText.Text;
        row[4] = MachineText.Text;
        row[5] = StartText.Text;
        row[6] = EndText.Text;
        row[7] = GoodText.Text;
        row[8] = BadText.Text;

        row2[1] = DateText.Text;
        row2[2] = IPNText.Text;
        row2[3] = MachineText.Text;
        row2[4] = MoldText.Text;
        row2[8] = GoodText.Text + BadText.Text; 

        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);       //This adds a row to Production Report Data Table
        ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row2);

        try                               //Officially adds the data to the last row of Production Report Data Table
        {
            objConnect.UpdateDatabase(ds);

            MaxRows = MaxRows + 1;        //Keeps track that we are updating the fact that our max rows has changed

            objConnect2.UpdateDatabase(ds2);

            MaxRows2 = MaxRows2 + 1;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
```